# Can I Use Dart Compiled JS (JavaScript) Into Firebase Hosting For Static Website

Tags: javascript, firebase, dart, angular-dart, firebase-hosting

I am Trying to deploy a static website with some DART Features. Before that I want to Know that Can I Use Dart Compiled JavaScript Code In it or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely!

In fact, you can configure your `firebase.json` file to run the build for you as part of deploy.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "predeploy": "rm -rf build; pub run build_runner build -o web:build --fail-on-severe --release"
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples/hacker_news_pwa for an example.

Comment: Always nice to see questions answered by the developers who created the frameworks in question

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting just serves static assets (e.g. HTML, CSS, JS, images).  It doesn't care what those assets are.  It performs no alteration of the assets on the way to the client.  You can use any web framework that serves static assets without any problems.